# Join ON Date Group

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate-functions

I have 3 tables;

Table 1

```
id   date
1    1132123123
2    1232342341

etc
```

Table 2

```
id   date
1    1132123123
2    1232342341

etc
```

Table 3

```
id   date
1    1132123123
2    1232342341

etc
```

All "date" columns are unix timestamps.

I am trying to join these 3 tables and count totals for each table respectively grouped by:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(date, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

Ideally, I'd like this result:

```
formatteddate   t1count   t2count   t3count
04-12-2011      2         2         2
04-13-2011      1         2         3
```

NOTE: The result doesn't match up to the example data, but I think it's pretty straight-forward.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.date, '%m-%d-%Y') as t1date,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.date, '%m-%d-%Y') as t2date,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(t3.date, '%m-%d-%Y') as t3date, 
  count(t1.id) as t1count,
  count(t2.id) as t2count,
  count(t3.id) as t3count
FROM
  t1,t2,t3
GROUP BY
  t1date
```

The query doesn't even load. t3 contains lots of data (1 million + records). t1 & t2, not so much.

Comment: You're doing a carthesian product. Use unions.

Comment: Are the timestamps unique within any single table?

Comment: Yes, the timestamps are unique for every single row in every single table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select from_unixtime(date,'%m-%d-%Y') as d,
sum(tb=1) as tb1,
sum(tb=2) as tb2,
sum(tb=3) as tb3
from (
select date,1 as tb from t1
union all
select date,2 from t2
union all
select date,3 from t3) as t
group by d
```

Comment: +1, just what I had in mind. Only my version would have looked slightly more ANSI-standard (MySQL isn't my 'native' SQL dialect).

Comment: Thanks. :) Do you mean somethin like sum(case when tb=1 then 1 else 0 end) as t1count, .... ?

Comment: this query loaded in 5 seconds unindexed. OMG Ponies answer didn't load at all :( Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. Just for curiosity how many records do you have?

Comment: I've got this quirk of always trying to use COUNT for counts (if possible), so in this case I would probably use something like `COUNT(CASE tb WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)`, which is far from being as laconic as your `SUM(tb = 1)`.

Comment: Lol:) With mysql I'm always laconic. :)

Comment: 1000 records t1, 1200000 records t2, 5000 records t3

Comment: I've since learned that COUNT can be used in MySQL like this: `COUNT(tb = 1 OR NULL)`. Here's a nice explanation, if needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011239/why-do-i-need-or-null-in-mysql-when-counting-rows-with-a-condition/5011311#5011311