# MySQL Query: count entries by status

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a log table with following schema:

```
OperatorId - JobId - Status ( Good/Bad/Ugly )
Alex         6       Good
Alex         7       Good
James        6       Bad
```

Description: Whenever an operator works on a job, an entry is made along with Status. That's it.

Now I need a report like:

```
OperatorId - Good Count - Bad Count - Ugly Count
Alex         2            0           0
James        0            1           0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select operatorid,
sum(if(status="good",1,0)) as good,
sum(if(status="bad",1,0)) as bad,
sum(if(status="ugly",1,0)) as ugly
from table
group by operatorid
```

Comment: aww... sum works like this in mysql as well? I thought it only works in SQL server like this. Anyway, thanks for posting the solution!

Comment: Actually I also thought the sum if syntax was specific to SQL Server. Never tried it in mysql.

Comment: You could even write it in a more concise way: sum(status="good") as good,sum(status="bad") as bad,sum(status="ugly") as ugly  ;)

Comment: I think double quotes are out of place here. String values should be delimited only with single quotes. Or is that not applicable to MySQL?

Comment: @Andriy M. You can use single quotes or even double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a Pivot Table.  It is done by setting a value 1 or 0 for each state and then summing them up:

```
SELECT 
  T.OperatorId,
  SUM(T.GoodStat) AS Good,
  SUM(T.BadStat) AS Bad,
  SUM(T.UglyStat) AS Ugly
FROM 
(
 SELECT 
   CASE WHEN Status = 'Good' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS GoodStat,
   CASE WHEN Status = 'Bad' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BadStat,
   CASE WHEN Status = 'Ugly' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS UglyStat,
   OperatorId
  FROM logTable T
)
GROUP BY T.OperatorId
```

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you prefer, whenever possible, to calculate counts with COUNT rather than with SUM, here's an alternative solution, which uses a method asked about in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011239/why-do-i-need-or-null-in-mysql-when-counting-rows-with-a-condition):

```
SELECT
  operatorid,
  COUNT(status = 'good' OR NULL) as good,
  COUNT(status = 'bad' OR NULL) as bad,
  COUNT(status = 'ugly' OR NULL) as ugly
FROM table
GROUP BY operatorid
```