# Mysql count id that appear in 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table with these columns:

- id
- user_id
- player_in
- player_out
- date

I need to make a report that count the number of repetitions each "player" both in player_in field, as in player_out field.
For example, if I have this 2 rows in the table (in the respective order).

```
id user_id player_in player_out
1  1       88        56
2  7       77        88
```

The result for the player 88 will be 2, and for the players 56 and 77, just 1

Comment: +1 I would like to know that too.

Comment: Would `SELECT COUNT(player_in), (SELECT COUNT(player_out) FROM myTable GROUP BY player_out) AS player_out FROM myTable GROUP BY player_in` work?

Comment: +1. nice way.I think you are so smart.

Comment: MySQL throw this error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery that employs `union all` to get the two column into one column, then use a standard `count(*)`:

Note: Thus query included individual totals for ins and outs as per further request in comments to this answer.

```
select
  player_id,
  count(*) as total,
  sum(ins) as ins,
  sum(outs) as outs
from (
  select
    player_in as player_id,
    1 as ins,
    0 as outs
  from mytable
  union all
  select player_out, 0, 1
  from mytable
) x
group by player_id
```

Note: you must use `union all` (not just `union`), because `union` removes duplicates whereas `union all` does not.

Comment: This works fine i think, I have a table with multiple rows and I cant count one by one to check this, but i think this work fine. Is there any way to optimize the query?

Comment: You could put separate indexes on player_in and player_out. Other than that, the query's about as simple as it gets - should perform fine.

Comment: Ok! one more question, how can i get the 3 items, "ins" "outs" and "total" for each player? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's actually a different question, but see answer for bonus edits to see how.

Comment: I have edited the query in my answer to return the total, total ins and total outs as you requested. Copy-paste it and try it.

Comment: This work excelent, thanks! if u want, edit your answer and add a comma after player_id, is the only mistake. Again, thanks!!

Comment: Added comma. (I typed this in on my iPhone... It can be harder to spot mistakes like that)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a cross-join to a 2-row virtual table to unpivot the `player_*` columns, then group the results, like this:

```
SELECT
  player,
  COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN x.is_in THEN t.player_in ELSE t.player_out END AS player
  FROM mytable t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT TRUE AS is_in UNION ALL SELECT FALSE) x
) s
GROUP BY
  player
;
```

That is, every row of the original table is essentially duplicated and each copy of the row supplies either `player_in` or `player_out`, depending on whether the derived table's `is_in` column is `TRUE` or `FALSE`, to form a single `player` column. This method of unpivoting might perform better than the UNION method [suggested by @Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17513172/297408) because this way the (physical) table is passed just once (but you'd need to test and compare both methods to determine if there's any substantial benefit to this approach in your particular situation).

To calculate in and out counts, as you have requested in one of your comments to the above mentioned answer, you could extend my original suggestion like this:

```
SELECT
  player,
  COUNT(    is_in OR NULL) AS in_count,
  COUNT(NOT is_in OR NULL) AS out_count,
  COUNT(*)                 AS total_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    x.is_in,
    CASE WHEN x.is_in THEN t.player_in ELSE t.player_out END AS player
  FROM mytable t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT TRUE AS is_in UNION ALL SELECT FALSE) x
) s
GROUP BY
  player
;
```

As you can see, the derived table now additionally returns the `is_in` column in its own right, and the column is used in two conditional aggregations for counting how many times a player was in and out. (If you are interested, the `OR NULL` trick is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011239/why-do-i-need-or-null-in-mysql-when-counting-rows-with-a-condition/5011311#5011311).)

You could also rewrite the `COUNT(condition OR NULL)` entries as `SUM(condition)`. That would certainly shorten both expressions, some also find the `SUM` method of counting clearer/more elegant. In either event, there would likely be no difference in performance, so choose whichever method suits your taste better.

A SQL Fiddle demo of the second query can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7a23/4).