# mysql displaying grouped columns base on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on a query that needs to output 'total engagements' by users in columns like 1 -eng column will display users who have one engagements, second column 2-eng which will display users who have done 2 engagements. Likewise 3eng, and so on. Note that the display should be like this. I have a engagement table which has userID. So I get distinct users like this

```
select count(distinct userID) from engagements
```

and I get engagements as

```
select count(*) from engagements
```

Engagements here refers to users who have either liked,replied,or shared the content

Please help. Thanks! I have used CASE and IF but unable to display in the below form

```
1eng             2eng          3eng 

100              200           100
```

Comment: Do you have any code at all?

Comment: Or at least your table schema?

Comment: I have the database schema which is engagements table( engagement_id(auto),  brandID, handle , postID ,userID ,engagementID , clikes, replies, content, posted(datetime), engagementType (likes,comment,etc)  ). I get these data into database from api

Comment: What are 100 and 200 in your result?

Comment: @user2865907 Consider updating your original question with that useful information

Comment: 100 represents 100 users who fall in 1 engagements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider returning the results in rows and pivoting them afterwards in your application.

To return the desired results in rows, you could use the following query:

```
SELECT
  engagementCount,
  COUNT(*) AS userCount
FROM (
  SELECT
    userID,
    COUNT(*) AS engagementCount
  FROM engagements
  GROUP BY userID
) AS s
GROUP BY engagementCount
;
```

Basically, you first group the `engagements` rows by `userID` and get the row counts per `userID`. Afterwards, you use the counts as the grouping criterion and count how many users were found with that count.

If you insist on returning the columnar view in SQL, you'll need to resort to dynamic SQL because of the indefinite number of columns in the final result set. You'd probably need to store the results of the inner SELECT temporarily, scan it to build the list of count expressions for every `engagementCount` value and ultimately construct a query of this kind:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(engagementCount = 1 OR NULL) AS `1eng`,
  COUNT(engagementCount = 2 OR NULL) AS `2eng`,
  COUNT(engagementCount = 3 OR NULL) AS `3eng`,
  ...
FROM temporary_storage
;
```

Or `SUM(engagementCount = value)` instead `COUNT(engagementCount = value OR NULL)`. (For me, the latter expresses the intention more explicitly, hence why I've suggested it first, but, in case you happen to prefer the `SUM` technique, there should be no discernible difference in performance between the two. The `OR NULL` trick is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011239/why-do-i-need-or-null-in-mysql-when-counting-rows-with-a-condition/5011311#5011311).)